# What is it the best way to replace custom lib version in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, esb, enterprise-integration, wso2-esb

I am using Enterprise Integrator 6.5.0.

I have a custom mediator that generate a file .jar that have a version 1.0.0, I saw when I put this .jar in the lib folder with the same version, all work fine. However, when I delete this .jar from lib folder and add the same .jar but with the version 1.0.1, I detected that the ESB was working with the 1.0.0 version.

Doing research, I saw that the ESB is generating two files, one in dropins folder and another in wso2\components\default\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\6\1.cp

So I think I need to delete manually the 3 files in order to add the new version.

Is there any other option to delete automatically this files or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a jar file to the lib directory, at the server startup the ESB server will convert the jar to an OSGI bundle and add to the dropins directory. If you want to remove the jar file it would be sufficient to remove the jar file from both the lib and dropins directory.

Make sure that when you add a new jar file you need to perform a server restart for the ESB server to pick up the new jar file